# What is the adverbial form of “communicational”?

Tags: adverbs, suffixes, dictionaries, affixes

I tried [*communicationally*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/communicationally), but the Free Dictionary doesn’t find it to be a word.

What I am trying to express is that someone is *communicationally challenged*, basically meaning they can’t communicate very well.

Comment: And what is wrong with "poor communicator?"  Does the language need this sort of cruft?

Comment: @ncmathsadist: *Cruft* is a new one on me! I've just found out what it means, but I'm prompted to [ask for more info](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93930/origin-and-scope-of-cruft)

Comment: Don't be afraid to create neologisms using the standard rules of adding prefixes, suffixes, and infixes to standard words. As Barrie says, though, _communicationally challenged_ is sardonic because all such PC-like terms are inherently parodistic and snarky. You've got to be a cynic to use them with effect and a turkey to believe that they mean what they seem to say (_viz._, I'm being kind and inoffensive here because I'm using a euphemism for _inarticulate_ and, probably, _stupid_).

Comment: What is the adjectival form of "communication"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just because a term does not appear in this or that dictionary does not make it “not a word”.  For one thing, the “Free Dictionary” falls short of being an accepted standard in the English language.

But for another,  ***productive affixes*** like *un-* and *-ly* can be applied to virtually any word from the target class to produce a perfectly viable new word. So even if you were using a little dictionary that happened to be missing an headword for something like *unceremoniously*, no one would ever question it if you used it.

So with your particular case of

> - *communicate > communication*
> - *communication > communicational*
> - *communicational > communicationally*

you certainly you *could* do so.  However, whether you *should* be creating such septasyllabic monsters is something else again; you might well want to use a longer phrase here instead.

You could just say they don’t communicate well, or that they’re poor communicators.  All those, and many others, seem an improvement over the ponderous *communicationally challenged*.

Comment: [Adverb] + _challenged_ is usually used with sardonic intent in a way that the alternatives aren’t.

Answer (score 3):

The most recent citation for **communicationally**

> *adv*. as regards communication; in respect of communications

…in my copy of the OED is in the context of *communicationally challenged*:

> 2004 *Daily Tel. (Sydney)* (Nexis) 14 June 19 : Mind you, if men weren't so communicationally challenged we women might not be driven to such drastic measures.

This is probably no coincidence, since it is a snug fit with the snowclone pattern:

> *[problem area]*-ly challenged

Depending on the context, though, you may also have the choice of using the word **communicatively**:

> *adv.* In a communicative manner; by means of communication; as regards communication

Notice that there is quite a bit of overlap in the definitions of the two words, and this form is 16 times more common than *communicationally* in the COCA. [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=communicationally%2Ccommunicatively&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows a similar disparity:

[image: Google Ngram of communicationally vs. communicatively]

Comment: @jwpat7 hmm, I thought I set it up so clicking the picture would take you to the ngram page, is it not working? Edit: I added a link in the text just in case.

Comment: The picture link looks ok – I didn't notice it before but now am unable to reproduce the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

The Wiktionary has an entry for [communicationally](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/communicationally).

But if you want another word, [incommunicable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incommunicable) means "who does not communicate freely".

The post was tagged "adverbs", but "communicationally challenged" as a whole is an adjective, and "incommunicable" is an adjective.

Comment: I think Wiktionary is mistaken about "incommunicable".  By analogy with similar words, "incommunicable" means "unable to _be communicated_", not "unable to communicate".  Of course, you can use it however you want, but if you take that view I recommend using "fnord" instead, as it's shorter and equally correct by those standards.

Answer (score 2):

There is an entry for *communicationally* in the Oxford English Dictionary with the definition 'as regards communication; in respect of communications.'